# NextGen stylesheets looking for localhost

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I've been running a local version of a site on which NextGen gallery plugin is installed. It's working great.

I uploaded to remote hosting and updated all "localhost" paths with the remote path in MySQL as part of my normal process. Unfortunately, the NextGen gallery plugin is still looking for localhost scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/~pathname/site-name/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/fancybox/nextgen_fancybox_init.js?ver=3.6'></script>
```

I've uninstalled the plugin, deleted the plugin files and then reinstalled but to no avail; it just keeps looking for local files.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:
 1. In the Dashboard, go to Gallery > Other options
 2. Click on "Lightbox effects" tab
 3. Click "Show advanced settings"
 4. In the text boxes, changes the stylesheet and javascript urls. Change from 'localhost' to your new path.
 5. Click save
 6. Done! It will now work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be stored in the database as a reference (although that would be odd). Try using this plugin to change all instances of localhost to your domain.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: I've already updated/changed all localhost references to the correct remote path in the database. So I'm really at a loss here. It must be in the plugin files somewhere but I have no idea where.

Comment: I think NextGen looks at the db for its url references. I cant see the developer leaving a localhost hardcoded anywhere. Why not give the velvet blues plugin a shot? I always miss things when in the DB. Doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: yeah i gave it a shot anyway and it didn't work; there were no local references in the db.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? I can look around the code a bit to see if I can find something.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/l8hs2p3

Comment: Actually, i did a db search for localhost and there are two in wp_bwps_log (better wp security), but have not been changed by velvet blues or by db search/replace.

Comment: also, did you use wp_enqueue for any of the scripts? it looks like there are 3 scripts that are still pointing to localhost.

Comment: initially yes, in the functions.php file. but these have now been deleted so there are now no scripts using wp_enqueue in that file.

Comment: ok. Im downloading the plugin now. Will see how they add these scripts in. Hopefully we can get this solved

Comment: It seems like a bug in the plugin. Someone else has reported that moving from localhost to a domain sometimes leaves references to localhost. Is there a way to change where nextgen tells things to point? havent really used it too much.

Comment: I did see some constants defined in the plugin, including some refereneces to folders that you have referenced as localhost, but it pulls from wordpress there.

Comment: Also, maybe try switching from fancybox to another lightbox and see if those scripts get included. then maybe switch back to fancybox

Comment: yeah, tried switching from fancybox to lightbox but that didn't help either.

Comment: where are the references to folders? i might have to hardcode them in.

Comment: Can you switch to lightbox and leave it for a bit? i wanna see if the references are the same.

Comment: The references are from nggallery.php

Comment: i found an advanced settings where i can change the folders *forehead slap* but there's still a localhost reference at line 505.

Comment: so most everything got fixed?

Comment: is the modal window working for you? it's not working on my android.

Comment: seems a few references are still in there with localhost. http://cl.ly/image/20220D2y2o3M

Comment: actually. its working now. must have been cache

Comment: i initially changed from fancybox to highslide and that wasn't working for some reason. i changed back to fancybox and now it's working. David, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The file location is there in Gallery >> Other options >> Lightbox >> show advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for the lightbox plugin. I had the same issues as others - ngg was inserting code that defined path variables leading to localhost. Updating the paths on Gallery > Other > Lightbox > Advanced made no difference; and there were no references to localhost in wp-options.

In the interest of time, I made a hack to the plugin js file that initializes lightbox.

The file is here:
plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/lightbox/static/jquery.lightbox/nextgen_lightbox_init.js

replace the function `nextgen_jquery_lightbox_init` with this:

```
var nextgen_jquery_lightbox_init = function() {
    var prefix = "www.my-website.com" // update here when you move to dev, localhost, etc.
    $('.ngg_lightbox').lightBox({
        imageLoading: "http:\/\/" + prefix + "\/wp-content\/plugins\/nextgen-gallery\/products\/photocrati_nextgen\/modules\/lightbox\/static\/jquery.lightbox\/lightbox-ico-loading.gif",
        imageBtnClose: "http:\/\/" + prefix + "\/wp-content\/plugins\/nextgen-gallery\/products\/photocrati_nextgen\/modules\/lightbox\/static\/jquery.lightbox\/lightbox-btn-close.gif",
        imageBtnPrev:  "http:\/\/" + prefix + "\/wp-content\/plugins\/nextgen-gallery\/products\/photocrati_nextgen\/modules\/lightbox\/static\/jquery.lightbox\/lightbox-btn-prev.gif",
        imageBtnNext:  "http:\/\/" + prefix + "\/wp-content\/plugins\/nextgen-gallery\/products\/photocrati_nextgen\/modules\/lightbox\/static\/jquery.lightbox\/lightbox-btn-next.gif",
        imageBlank:    "http:\/\/" + prefix + "\/wp-content\/plugins\/nextgen-gallery\/products\/photocrati_nextgen\/modules\/lightbox\/static\/jquery.lightbox\/lightbox-blank.gif"                                                                                                                                                                      
    });  
};
```

This code overrides the original function by using the variables defined in the function rather than the incorrect ones that ngg inserts into the head. Whenever you move the site, you'll need to update the `prefix` var in the js file. Not the prettiest solution but hey it works!